# Can't start firewalld

Tags: iptables, centos7, firewalld

I restarted my VPS and now `firewalld` isn't running and I can't seem to start it.

```
# systemctl is-enabled firewalld
enabled

# systemctl is-active firewalld
active

# firewall-cmd --state
not running

# firewall-cmd --reload
Error: '/sbin/ip6tables -t raw -I PREROUTING 2 -m rpfilter --invert -j DROP' failed: ip6tables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

I'm at a loss for what to do next. I'm not sure where this `iptables` rule is defined. I know if I try to type the command by itself:

```
# /sbin/ip6tables -t raw -I PREROUTING 2 -m rpfilter --invert -j DROP
ip6tables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

This is CentOS7

Comment: Please post the output of `virt-what`. (If it's not installed, install it first.)

Comment: Its openvz. This was all working fine a few days ago. It wasn't until I restarted the VPS that all this weirdness began.

Comment: I discovered that the above error is related to the `firewalld.conf` setting `IPv6_rpfilter=yes`. If I set it to `no`, then I don't get the error anymore. But I'm not clear about if I need to have that setting enabled or not.

Comment: Your host broke it. They will have to fix it.